# 2 strings, 1 encoding, different values

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, web-scraping

I have two strings which I get by scraping from website. String value is 'Çorap', but they show different in web browser:

**PHP code for testing:**

```
  echo '<h1> string: '.strtolower('çorap').' encoding: '.mb_detect_encoding(strtolower('çorap')).'</h1>';
  echo '<h1> string: '.strtolower('Çorap').' encoding: '.mb_detect_encoding(strtolower('Çorap')).'</h1>';
```

**Result:**

```
 string: Ã§orap encoding: UTF-8
 string: Ã‡orap encoding: UTF-8
```

What is the problem here? And how can I achieve the first string to be like the second?

Comment: In what encoding is scraped website, and in what encoding do you wish to show this string to user?

Comment: I want utf-8 as in second string

Comment: website is also utf-8

Comment: Then there is a problem in scraping. How do you do that?

Comment: @Glavić If you want you can check it

Comment: If you wish to lower utf-8 character, you will need `mb_strtolower()` function. And why do you need `mb_detect_encoding()` if you know data is UTF8?

Comment: @Glavić Just tried with mb_strtolower() the same result. I need to compare these strings

Comment: So, compare them... `var_dump( 'çorap' === mb_strtolower('Çorap') );` is returning `TRUE`.

Comment: @Glavić +1 for comparing, but that does not explain the reason why they are different

Comment: ... and the reason why you see `Ã§orap` instead of `çorap`, it that you don't have UTF8 encoding! Add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Glavić thanks. Please add your comments as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61952/discussion-between-torayeff-and-glavic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing string `çorap` as `Ã§orap`, that means you have invalid encoding set, try:

```php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

You cannot lowercase UTF8 string with `strtolower()` function, try:

```php
var_dump( 'çorap' === mb_strtolower('Çorap', 'UTF-8') );
```

Comment: var_dump( 'çorap' === mb_strtolower('Çorap', 'UTF-8') );

Comment: @torayeff: yes :) I have UTF-8 set as default `mbstring.internal_encoding`, so I don't need to worry about always writing 2nd parameter.